# How to handle multiple JOIN and LEFT JOINS in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables that need to be joined. These tables have to do with orders placed by customers and the orders turned into purchase orders for the relevant suppliers.

- Table `product_sale` holds the customers products that they've ordered.
- Table `product` holds the main information on those products.
- Table `sale_purchase` is a bridging table between the sale and purchase order.

  - Note: This may or may not exist as the product might be out of stock and no purchase order was required.
- Table `product_purchase` holds those linked products on the purchase order.
- Table `grn` handles the receiving of those products.

Unfortunately in the customers sales order, I will need to access information from all of these tables. Here's the query I have so far:

```sql
SELECT
    ps.*,
    pp.received_qty,
    p.group_ref,
    p.subgroup_ref, 
    g.grn_id AS 'grn_ref',
    g.grn_date
FROM
    product_sale ps 
    INNER JOIN product          p  ON ps.product_ref = p.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN  sale_purchase    sp ON ps.sale_ref    = sp.sale_ref 
    LEFT JOIN  product_purchase pp ON pp.so_line_no  = ps.line_no 
    LEFT JOIN  grn              g  ON g.grn_id       = pp.grn_ref 
WHERE
    ps.sale_ref = 150002
GROUP BY
    line_no
ORDER BY
    line_no
```

So far so good, although the `received_qty` for one line is wrong:

[image]

The first line's received qty should be 7 and not 4. I've checked the grn table and it definitely says 7. Can I please get some help as to where I am going wrong with this query? Also the grn_ref and grn_date should be NULL for line_no 1.00

Comment: You're not using any aggregation functions with `GROUP BY`. So you're selecting values from random rows in each `line_no` group.

Comment: ...are you using MySQL 5.x? If so, then that explains [why it's letting you run a meaningless query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). You should update to MariaDB or at least MySQL 8.x - or at least, [enable the  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: You must have different quantities for different products in `line_no = 1.00`. One of them is 4, another is 7. Why should the result prefer 7?

Comment: When line_no 1.00 only get's partly received (say 4), it generates a new line_no 1.01 with 4 as received and line_no 1.02 as 0 received. It updates the main parent line_no 1.00 as each line gets received. Thus, when line_no 1.02 get's received (3), it also updates the main parent line.

Comment: @jamiegfinch Do you understand what the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option does... or not?

Comment: No I haven't seen the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. I'm trying to read up on it, but it seems pretty confusing. What's it all about?

Comment: @Dai, I'm using 10.4.20-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Scrap it guys. I figured it out. I hadn't accounted for another purchase order that was in the system. Solution to the problem was adding `AND pp.purchase_ref = sp.purchase_ref` to the left join for product_purchase. See revised code below:

```
SELECT
        ps.*,
        pp.received_qty,
        p.group_ref,
        p.subgroup_ref, 
        g.grn_id AS 'grn_ref',
        g.grn_date
    FROM
        product_sale ps 
        INNER JOIN product          p  ON ps.product_ref = p.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN  sale_purchase    sp ON ps.sale_ref    = sp.sale_ref 
        LEFT JOIN  product_purchase pp ON pp.so_line_no  = ps.line_no AND pp.purchase_ref = sp.purchase_ref
        LEFT JOIN  grn              g  ON g.grn_id       = pp.grn_ref 
    WHERE
        ps.sale_ref = 150002
    GROUP BY
        line_no
    ORDER BY
        line_no
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).